# 400 Bad request trying to POST to a Spring endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

Trying to post this to my Spring api

```
{
    "test1":"test1",
    "test2":"test2",
    "test3":"test3"
}
```

But i keep getting a `400 Bad Request` response.

Controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/api")
public class DokumentController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody TestDTO body) {
        System.out.println(body.getTest1());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

TestDTO looks like this:

```
public class TestDTO {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;

    TestDTO(String test1, String test2, String test3) {
        this.test1 = test1
        this.test2 = test2
        this.test3 = test3
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    //And so on..

}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle `@PostMapping` is fine

Comment: @Jens I'm using Postman. Added the JSON in the body as raw JSON(application/json)

Comment: Hm weird. Might be how I'm sending the request then. It seems like spring is unable to map to my TestDTO class. No clue why

Comment: @mTv Do you see any error in the logfiles?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: A, log says: `Cannot construct instance of TestDTO: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)`

Comment: @mTv Do oyu have a contructor in your TestDTO class?

Comment: @Jens Yes sorry forgot to add it to this question, added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a constructor with no arguments in your DTO class:

```
public class TestDTO {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
    private String test3;

    //Default no argument constructor
    TestDTO() {
    }

    TestDTO(String test1, String test2, String test3) {
        this.test1 = test1
        this.test2 = test2
        this.test3 = test3
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    //And so on..

}
```

The Jackson Framework creates the class first and uses reflection to set the values.